# Access to Identity 'my-identity-that-exists-in-cognito-identity-browser' is forbidden

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

Let's say you implement two external providers like [Twitter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/twitter/) and [Facebook](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/facebook/) What is the correct, best practice JSON document for the Authenticated IAM role trust relationship. I have tried reading this [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies) and this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/web-identity-federation.html) But i'm still having issues. My current policy is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:mypool"      
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I keep getting the failure

> Access to Identity 'my-identity-that-exists-in-cognito-identity-browser' is forbidden.

This only started breaking after I switched from developer provided authentication to one of Amazon's providers. I can't really find any examples besides very standard setups, and I'm having issues trying to grok this documentation.

**UPDATE**

Developer error. As @jeff-bailey suggested, you must make sure your provider has the correct logins map. Following the examples are not enough to satisfy all situations. In my case, I have extremely sticky sessions that persist across app terminations and even reinstallation. If you have your social tokens already and skip a traditional login screen you *must* not forget to set your tokens. You can't just rely on fabric/facebook authentication callback.

Comment: Our [iOS sample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Objective-C) supports authentication for all public providers via a single identity pool with no modification necessary.

Comment: @BobKinney I modified the policy so much, i no longer know what the autogenerated trust relationship is for a cognitoAuth role.

Comment: In the blog post you linked, in the first policy replace unauthenticated with authenticated and you have the the default trust policy.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'm running into an issue where my own developer rolled credentials (still live) are clobbering my new identities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you're using two pools for two providers as opposed to just using one? Cognito limits you to one application per provider per pool, but you can use different providers in the same pool, which would allow you to use the standard roles.

Edit:  It sounds like the logins map contents might hold the issue. Future calls with an authenticated id have to have the same login token that was linked to it. So, if you created an identity id with Twitter auth, attempting to use that id without that Twitter token will give you that exception. Be sure you're including it/properly resuming app session on app restart...etc.
I'd give that a second look, if you're not that would definitely cause that issue.

Comment: The pool I am connecting with is actually different than the one that is giving this error, and so I added the second pool in case there was some developer error going on in my part.

Comment: Actually, this error is for an *identity*, not identity pool, my bad, let me remove the other pool id from the policy and see what happens

Comment: Strange, the identity that is forbidden was created without problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3l9apw91h3yb71/Screenshot%202015-07-28%2019.44.28.png?dl=0  Maybe there is something wrong with my syntax setting the logins property?

Comment: If the identity was created without issue, I would think it's along those lines. Are you trying to access the authenticated id without including the token you gave when creating it? That's one possible reason. If nothing stands out, it might be worth taking a look at the sample Bob linked above to check the authentication syntax.

Comment: See edit, I'd make sure you're including the token whenever you call Cognito.

Comment: Yeah, this feels like developer error,  i have a feeling it's related to my backend that is still using my own authentication and now identifies are being stored incorrectly/misused, i'll do more investigation and fix/update this question.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, could it be because of this?  "Note: If you created your identity pool before February 2015, you will need to reassociate your roles with your identity pool in order to use this constructor without the roles as parameters. To do so, open the Amazon Cognito console, select your identity pool, click Edit Identity Pool, specify your authenticated and unauthenticated roles, and save the changes." I just recently switched to the modern initializer...

Comment: Ok working smoothly now, since i just recently switched to `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: Config.get("COGNITO_POOL"))` style instantiation I reassigned my roles just in case. I also removed my backend `identity.get_open_id_token_for_developer_identity` since identities and  tokens were being persisted in dynamodb that clients "in the wild" including my own device were managing, probably causing identity_id collision with incorrect logins map. Anyways, thanks for the extra set of eyes on this one.

Comment: Just in case someone else stumbles on to this, your point on making sure tokens are set on app start are spot on. I have *very* sticky logins with coredata/keychain/icloud, but was only settings my logins on fabric login callback, which is 100% incorrect, as on app termination, a relaunch will skip the authentication process leaving the provider not properly set up. Prior to switching I subclassed `AWSAbstractIdentityProvider` which was handling all of this for me, when i switched i failed to think about application lifecycle

Comment: Glad to hear it's up and running!